# Users permission to files

Tags: c#, asp.net

our team just work on a project which works on an Automation system. we use ASP.NET technology.here is my Question:
We have some users that could access to some Official letter on a Directory.for example here is a link: 192.168.1.1/home/Documents/1/Example.DOC
each user have it's own user and password and they are on local office network. if a user could use the link above so he can copy and paste it on browser and access to files. we need some solution that denied users to access file directly in our server.so our application should get the file from directory and return it as new link to user.so if the user copy/paste it again he can not get the file because the virtual link has absolute. what solution do you recommend? Thanks all.

Comment: use a handler (.ascx) in asp.net that returns the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User handler (.ashx) to return a file. The handler can check if user has permission for file. If the file should be downloaded only once lazy method (without some file ticket system) is to limit download availability to just few minutes - i.e. make a redirect to .ashx from your page and add symmetrically encrypted timestamp

```
Response.Redirect(@"/GetFile.ashx?Timestamp=[Symmetrically Encrypted Current Date and Time]&FileName=Example.doc");
```

And in handler check if timestamp is valid (not older than few minutes) and serve the file.